# Dispatching Events in ANE

Tags: android, apache-flex, events, mobile, adobe

Coding an Air Native Extension:

How do you dispatch an event from the android native code and have the actionscript interface part of the ANE be listening for that event and also hear it?

I have looked everywhere and I can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

as3 part

```
package com.yourpackage
{
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.StatusEvent;
    import flash.external.ExtensionContext;

    public class EventCaller extends EventDispatcher
    {
        private var context:ExtensionContext;

        public function EventCaller(target:IEventDispatcher=null)
        {
            super(target);      
            if(!context)
                context = ExtensionContext.createExtensionContext("com.yourpackage", null);
            if(context)
                context.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS,statusHandle);
        }
        // listener function
        public function statusHandle(event:StatusEvent):void{
            trace(event);
            // process event data
        }

        public function requestEvent():void{
            context.call("requestEvent");
        }
    }
}
```

java part (just function part)

```
public class RequestEvent implements FREFunction {  

    @Override
    public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] args) {

               // dispatching event
               context.dispatchStatusEventAsync("someCode", "someLevel");

               Boolean value = true;               
               return FREObject.newObject(value);
        }
}
```